# Prove that $|z_{n+2}-z_{n+1}|\leq q\cdot|z_{n+1}-z_n| \implies (z_n)_{n\geq 1} \text{ converges}$ when $q\in (0,1)$

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, proof-verification

**Problem:**

Let $q\in (0,1)$ and $(z_n)_{n\geq 1} \subset \mathbb{C}$ be a sequence. Prove:$$|z_{n+2}-z_{n+1}|\leq q\cdot|z_{n+1}-z_n| \implies (z_n)_{n\geq 1} \text{ converges}$$

**My attempt:**

$$|z_{n+2}-z_{n+1}|\leq q\cdot|z_{n+1}-z_n| \Longleftrightarrow \bigg |\frac{z_{n+2}-z_{n+1}}{z_{n+1}-z_n} \bigg | \leq q$$ If we want to remove the absolute value bars, we must note that $z_{n+2}\geq z_{n+1}$ and $z_{n+1}\geq z_n$ **or** $z_{n+2}\leq z_{n+1}$ and $z_{n+1}\leq z_n$, hence $(z_n)$ is either monotonically decreasing or monotonically increasing. Furthermore the quotient is either bounded above or bounded below, thus $(z_n)_n$ is convergent.  $\Box$

Comment: What does "remove the absolute value bars" mean?  You don't have an ordering on $\mathbb{C}$ compatible with its natural topology.

Comment: Hmmm, I mean that the absolute value bars become redundant if the latter inequalites hold

Answer (score 1):

Intuition/Hint:

Take $q=1/2$, $z_0=0$ and $z_1=1$.
What can you say about $|z_n-z_{n-1}|$ for any given $n$?
Further, what can you say about $|z_n-z_m|$ for any given $n$ and $m$?

---

Here's a handy criterion (whose name I forgot) for convergence: $\{z_n\}$ converges if
$$
\lim_{N \to \infty} \sup_{m,n>N} |z_n-z_m|=0.
$$

Comment: The criterion reminds me of cauchy's.

Comment: @ParabolicAlcoholic that's because it is. This clearly implies being a Cauchy sequence - if the limit is zero then for every epsilon the supremum (and thus a given pair) must eventually be less than it for big enough $N$.

Answer (score 0):

You can’t say $z_{n+1} \ge z_n$; there is no “greater than” or “less than” in complex numbers.

Instead, note that by repeatedly applying the given formula, $|z_{n+1} - z_n| \le q |z_n - z_{n-1}| \le q^2 |z_{n-1}-z_{n-2} \ldots \le q^n |z_2 - z_1|$. Note that $|z_{n+1} - z_n|$ is the distance between the points $z_{n+1}$ and $z_n$ and is bounded by a geometric progression with ratio less than $1$. We now consider the two components separately, noting that difference in the $x$ coordinate is at most the distance between the two points. So we have $|x_{n+1} - x_n| \le q^n c$ for some constant $c$; this is bounded by a geometric series and so $x_n$ must converge (try proving this yourself)! The same holds for the $y$-coordinate, so $z_n$ converges.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. Could you please elaborate a little? I can't follow.